# Public folder index file is not executing in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

When I execute my index file in public folder of laravel, its giving me an error message like this:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Comment: You should probably demonstrate the code that is causing/getting the error if you need people to help you with it...

Comment: Did you check your database connection ? Does it exist when you use "php artisan serve" command ?

Comment: This is not an issue directly related to Laravel. You have either put at least one wrong parameter (user/pass/server/port), or maybe even MySQL is not listening to that specific port, OR you might have a firewall that blocks connections on port 8888

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue directly related to Laravel. You might have a firewall that blocks connections on port 8000. So Default laravel port does not working.

Comment: If you're going to attempt to hijack someone else's comment as your own answer, at least get the port right.